# Почему программа дает на выходе None вместо необходимого return`a?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Программа должна проверить пароль, вернуть строку с указанием качества пароля, но самый тупой аргумент в виде `"qwerty"`, который, по идее, должен падать еще на 2 проверке, идет до конца и выдает `None`. Кто-нибудь понимает, почему?
(Проверки достаточно типичные: по типу длинны, состава (цифры и буквы))

```
def password_level(password):
    if len(password) < 6:
        return 'Недопустимый пароль'
    elif password.isalpha and (password.lower == password or password.upper == password):
        return 'Ненадежный пароль'
    elif not password.isalpha:
        return 'Ненадежный пароль'
    elif any(map(str.isdigit, password)) and (password.upper == password or password.lower == password):
        return 'Слабый пароль'
    elif any(map(str.isdigit, password)) and password.upper != password and password.lower != password:
        return 'Надежный пароль'
print(password_level("qwerty"))
```

Comment: потому что если не выполняется ни одно из условий - функция ничего не возвращает, что равносильно `return None`

Comment: Да, я это понимаю. Не понимаю, почему не проходит условие)

Comment: в конце кода он есть в вызове функции, а также написан в вопросе

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас функции `lower` и `upper` не вызывались, из-за чего сравнение было ссылки на функцию (например, `password.lower`) и строки (`password`)

Теперь работает:

```
def password_level(password):
    if len(password) < 6:
        return 'Недопустимый пароль'
    elif password.isalpha and (password.lower() == password or password.upper() == password):
        return 'Ненадежный пароль'
    elif not password.isalpha:
        return 'Ненадежный пароль'
    elif any(map(str.isdigit, password)) and (password.upper() == password or password.lower() == password):
        return 'Слабый пароль'
    elif any(map(str.isdigit, password)) and password.upper() != password and password.lower() != password:
        return 'Надежный пароль'
    
print(password_level("qwerty"))
# Ненадежный пароль
```

Comment: Fuck. Настолько тупая ошибка)) Спасибо)

Comment: @sayfdor, пожалуйста :) удачи :)

Answer (score 2):

Результат None появляется из-за того, что ни одно из условий не выполняется.

Исправленный код:

```
def password_level(password):
    if len(password) < 6:
        return 'Недопустимый пароль'
    elif password.isalpha and (password.lower() == password or password.upper() == password):
        return 'Ненадежный пароль'
    elif not password.isalpha:
        return 'Ненадежный пароль'
    elif any(map(str.isdigit, password)) and (password.upper() == password or password.lower() == password):
        return 'Слабый пароль'
    elif any(map(str.isdigit, password)) and password.upper() != password and password.lower() != password:
        return 'Надежный пароль'
print(password_level("qwerty"))
```

Comment: Это я понимаю, но почему он не подходит... хз)